# Glassfish Full Stacktrace in webpages

Tags: glassfish, stack-trace, http-status-code-500

For debugging purposes, I am searching a way to display the full stack trace in error 500 webpage.

For now, I've got this :

[image]

**Server:** Glassfish 5.1

Best regards

SK